# "Save primefaces chart as" with export function

Tags: java, javascript, primefaces

I use Primefaces 3.4 with Apache MyFaces 2.1.8 on WebSphere Application Srever 8.

I have some charts. Now I want to make it possible to save the chart as image.
With PF comes the export function for charts.

In PF showcase they export the image in a new dialog:
[look here](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/chartExport.jsf)

I want to get the typical "save as" dialog when I push the button.

Can someone give me a hint how to write the javascript for this?

It's something like this:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
        //         
        function exportChart() {
            //export image
            $('#chart').exportAsImage();
        }
        //
    </script>
```

Best regards

Comment: Do you generated your charts on the fly with javascript? In the showcase there is also an Dynamic Image Streaming example of a chart(http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/dynamicImage.jsf). Then you can make use of the primefaces <p:fileDownload> (http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/fileDownload.jsf) But i don't know if that is an option for you.

Answer (score 0):

I am late but hope it will help others to solve the problem.
Make sure that "chart" and "dlg" are javascript variable

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //         
    function exportChart() {
        //export image
        $('#output').empty().append(chart.exportAsImage());

        //show the dialog  
        dlg.show();
    }
    //
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The image exported is an image base 64. You can use next:

```
yourInputText.value = chart.exportAsImage().src;
```